# Add Time from TimeSpan Object in Powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime, variables, timespan

This has been driving me nuts, and it's got to be something simple I'm missing.

I'm simply trying to get the total hours from a `TimeSpan` object and use that to add to a `DateTime` object.

```
$mytime = "1/1/2020 10:00:00"
$hours = (New-TimeSpan -Start $mytime).TotalHours
Get-Date
(Get-Date $mytime).AddHours($hours)
```

The result is

> Wednesday, February 5, 2020 11:25:37 AM
>
> Wednesday, February 5, 2020 11:25:37 AM

In the above, the time doesn't change!  However if I just assign a value to `$hours`, it works fine.

```
$mytime = "1/1/2020 10:00:00"
$hours = 100
Get-Date
(Get-Date $mytime).AddHours($hours)
```

> Wednesday, February 5, 2020 11:25:37 AM
>
> Sunday, January 5, 2020 5:00:01 AM

I've tried all manner of variable assignments and casting, but no matter what I do I can't get the `TotalHours` value to work.  Why can't I use `$hours`? `TotalHours` is supposed to be a normal `double`, and even if I cast it to `double` (`[double]$hours = New-Timespan...`) nothing changes.

Comment: You are showing two output items, but your code only has one line that outputs an object. As I see it, the code is working as expected. Could you expand on the problem and expected behavior?

Comment: I agree, we need the expected behavior here. What you are doing with `(New-TimeSpan -Start $mytime).TotalHours` is returning the total number of hours elapsed from `1/1/2020 10:00:00` to **the current time** (since you did not specify an `-End`). If you take the total hours elapsed from 10AM new year's day to now, and add that number of hours to 10AM on new years day, you're going to get damn close to the current time.

Comment: Sorry @logicaldiagram, you're right.  I added the get-date to the code sample.  Seems like PowerShell is converting a normal "number", but when I pass it the double it's not.  Adding [int] to my call is working.

Comment: Why are you comparing 841 hours to 100 hours?  Oh, I see, the date is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TotalHours` includes fractional hours. The value of `$hours` will be something like `844.1311....`. The value of `TotalHours` is basically:

```
$ts = New-TimeSpan -Start $mytime
$ts.Ticks / [TimeSpan]::TicksPerHour
```

If you want the integer value, try:

```
$mytime = "1/1/2020 10:00:00"
$hours = [math]::Truncate((New-TimeSpan -Start $mytime).TotalHours)
(Get-Date $mytime).AddHours($hours)
```

I haven't tested it, but you might need to use `Math.Floor()` instead if you can potentially have `$mytime` in the future.

Truthfully, though, if you want the same hour of day today as another date, it's more logical to do this:

```
$mytime = Get-Date "1/1/2020 10:00:00"
$today = (Get-Date).Date
$today.AddHours($mytime.Hour)
```

Or:

```
$mytime = Get-Date "1/1/2020 10:00:00"
[DateTime]::Today.AddHours($mytime.Hour)
```

Comment: $hours = [int](New-TimeSpan -Start $mytime).TotalHours did the trick.  Don't know why Powershell is convering numbers sometimes and not others, but I'm sure there's a good reason.

Comment: @insane4 Beware that casting to int is a *rounding* operation. Compare `[int](844.4)` to `[int](844.6)`.

Comment: @BaconBits plus powershell does "banker's rounding" differently on even and odd numbers `[int]844.5; [int]845.5`.  Perhaps truncate is ideal `[math]::truncate(844.5)`

Comment: Yeah, you can control the rounding operation to always round up (or down for negative numbers), but doing that requires calling the Math.Round() function: `[System.Math]::Round(844.5, [System.MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero); [System.Math]::Round(845.5, [System.MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero)`. The system defaults to using `[System.MidpointRounding]::ToEven`, which is "banker's rounding" as you say.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  You're adding 844.4 hours (35 days) in the first example, the number of hours to get to the current day and time, and 100 hours (4 days) in the second.

```
$mytime = "1/1/2020 10:00:00"
$hours = (New-TimeSpan -Start $mytime).TotalHours
$hours
844.404845696333
(Get-Date $mytime).AddHours($hours)

Wednesday, February 5, 2020 2:24:17 PM


$mytime = "1/1/2020 10:00:00"
$hours = 100
(Get-Date $mytime).AddHours($hours)

Sunday, January 5, 2020 2:00:00 PM
```

Here's another example:

```
[datetime]'2:28pm' + (new-timespan -Hours 1)

Wednesday, February 5, 2020 3:28:00 PM
```

If it's under 24 hours, it can be as simple as ([timespan] is implied in the 2nd argument):

```
[datetime]'2:28pm' + '1:0'

Wednesday, February 5, 2020 3:28:00 PM
```

Subtracting two datetimes:

```
[datetime]"Wednesday, February 5, 2020 11:25:37 AM" - [datetime]"1/1/2020 10:00:00"


Days              : 35
Hours             : 1
Minutes           : 25
Seconds           : 37
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 30291370000000
TotalDays         : 35.0594560185185
TotalHours        : 841.426944444444
TotalMinutes      : 50485.6166666667
TotalSeconds      : 3029137
TotalMilliseconds : 3029137000
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the problem is that `1/1/2020 10:00:00` plus 844 hours is `2/5/2020 14:00:00`, not `2/5/2020 14:24:17`. I believe that the intent is to get the same hour today without the minutes or seconds.